# Why is it that "alle" takes different cases here?

Tags: tense, grammar-identification

In my german worksheet I saw a sentence "Im Bad wurde alles neu gemacht, alle Türen und Wände wurden frisch gestrichen"

Why do we use "wurde" for the first "all" but "wurden" for the second "all"?

Comment: It doesn't. 1) "wurde" and "wurden" differ in number, not in case (they are verbs, so they have no case). 2) "alles" and "alle" do not differ in case, but in word class: "alles" is a pronoun (like "everything" in English), while "alle" is an adverb or determiner (like "all" in English) - see RoyPJ's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*"Alles"* behaves like *'everything'*.

*"Alle"* behaves like *'all'*.

> Alles *ist* schön. 
>   Everything *is* beautiful.
>
> Alle Dinge *sind* schön. 
>   All things *are* beautiful.

If you are further interested in different variations of *"all-"* and your German is good enough, there is an article in the [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/all) about it.